# How add styled-components as an external for the rollup build?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, rollupjs, styled-components

I'm trying to add styled-components in my `rollup.config.js` as the reproduction below, but it throw an error. I had the similar issue for `react-router-dom` and solved it by renaming `react-router-dom` into `react-router-dom/Link` in externals of `rollup.config.js`.

How to do with `styled-components` ?

**Reproduction:**

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  ...
  external: ['react', 'react-router-dom/Link', 'styled-components'],
  ...
  globals: { react: 'React', 'react-router-dom/Link': 'Link', 'styled-
  components: 'styled' },
};
```

**Actual Behavior:** Throw error when build with rollup

```
(babel plugin) An unexpected situation arose. Please raise an issue at 
https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues. Thanks!
node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.es.js
```

**Version styled-components:** 2.0.1

**Version rollup-plugin-babel:** 2.7.1

Comment: I have a similar issues with this -_-

Answer (score 2):

Finally I resolve my need with this in my rollup.config.js

```
export default {
  ...
  external: ['styled-components'],
  ...
  globals: { 'styled-components': 'styled' },
};
```

It's depend on how we import the package, in my case I import it in my files as:

`import styled from 'styled-components';`